# Where can I find source for Joomla chrome templates?

Tags: module-display, module-style, custom-module

I want to add custom chrome for my modules, and I'd like to take peek at source of standard chrome styles in Joomla but I can't find their location.

If anyone can help it's much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Found it!

Source of joomla chrome styles can be found in:

```
/templates/system/html/modules.php
```

Answer (score 5):

To override those defaults you just need to place a file called modules.php in a folder called html in your template, e.g.: `/templates/[your default template]/html/modules.php`.

Then you can apply your custom module chrome either by specifying it in index.php of your template or within the module settings.